# Pointer incrementation, dereferencing and comparsion in a loop

Tags: c

Don't these two mean the same thing, first get the value and then increment?

```
for ( ; *s == *t; s++, t++)

for ( ; *s++ == *t++;)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No if the for loop have content that refers to `s` and `t`. The first loop can be rewritten as

```
while (true)
{
   bool are_equal = *s == *t;
   if (!are_equal) break;

   // Perform stuff inside the for loop
   // Note that 's' and 't' are not increased yet in here.

   ++ s;
   ++ t;
}
```

The second loop can be rewritten as

```
while (true)
{
   bool are_equal = *s == *t;
   ++ s;
   ++ t;
   if (!are_equal) break;

   // Perform stuff inside the for loop
   // Note that 's' and 't' have been increased in here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They both do the comparison before the increment but if the loop body is not empty the first version will increase s and t *after* the body while the second version will increase them *before* the body.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( ; *s == *t; s++, t++)
```

is equivalent to:

```
while (*s == *t)
{
    ...
    s++;
    t++
}
```

while:

```
for ( ; *s++ == *t++;)
```

is equivalent to:

```
while (*s++ == *t++)
{
    ...
}
```

The important difference is that in the first case s and t are incremented at the *end* of the loop body, whereas in the first case they are incremented at the *start* of the loop body.

One further difference is that s and t are incremented one more tiem in the second loop than in the first loop. In the first case s and t may not even be incremented at all (if `s[0] != t[0]`) whereas in the second case they will always be incremented at least once ( even if `s[0] != t[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

The loop would run for the same number of times, but there is a difference is in the body of the loop: the first loop would see original `s` and `t`, while the second one would see them post-increment.